# Wordpress Re-usable Custom Widget

Tags: wordpress

I created a custom widget for wordpress.  But I can only use it once.  I can't assign multiple instances of the widget to my sidebars.

Can anyone show me sample code on how to make my custom widgets re-useable?

Comment: Why can't you assign multiple instances? What happens and where?

Comment: FRom the WP interface, after I drag the widget from the left panel into the sidebar, no new instance regenerates in the left panel. Thus, I don't hae additional instances of that widget.  I suspect all I need to do is add a parameter somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Check out this tut on [reusable WordPress widgets](http://wpmututorials.com/how-to/a-reusable-widget/) :)</strike>

Using the [2.8 widget API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_2.8#New_Widgets_API), widgets are natively re-usable.

Comment: yeah, i was looking at that and it's so lengthy...i suspect things shouldn't be that difficult...

Comment: Scrap that tut - seems since 2.8 widgets are natively re-usable! http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_2.8#New_Widgets_API